# Retrieve all groups for a member using Google Admin java sdk

Tags: google-api, google-api-java-client, google-admin-sdk

I would like to retrieve all groups for a given member.
There is an api interface for this:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-groups#get_all_member_groups

But unfortunately I can't figure out how to do that using java SDK as I was not able to find a method for this.
How can this problem be solved?

Comment: if you are successful, could you please share the code with me. I am struggling with this admin-api

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add methods, you can use Directory.Groups.List and set the userKey parameter, something like

```
//... imports, initializations etc.

Directory service = new Directory.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory,
    credential).build();

Groups userGroups = service.groups().list().setUserKey("member@domain.com")
    .execute();
```

Comment: yep that's the stuff

Comment: Do you know where I can find sample code for the `credential` Object in java? https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/java provides a sample but its for a command line application. And https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer provides code that is not in Java. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add new method to class com.google.api.services.admin.directory.Directory class to query https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups?userKey={userKey}. This way you can retrieve the member's groups.